# Приближённый вид сайта при загрузке на мобильном устройстве

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Есть сайт в котором фиксированная ширина для всех размеров экранов.

```
<div style="   
    height: 700px;
    width: 1349px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;">
</div>
<div style="   
    height: 700px;
    width: 1349px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;">
</div>
<div style="   
    height: 700px;
    width: 1349px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;">
</div>
```

При загрузке сайта на мобильном телефоне он первым делом отображается не весь, а хотелось бы что бы при загрузке страницы сразу была видна вся ширина сайта.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Имеется ввиду масштаб не тот при загрузке? Надо чтобы сайт помещался весь в ширину экрана?

Comment: @Skywave Да, нужно что бы ввел адрес сайта, он открылся сразу весь в ширину, что бы просмотреть нужно приближать. А сейчас открывается только кусочек сайта при загрузке, приходиться уменьшать масштаб, что бы разобраться что к чему.

Comment: Посмотрите есть ли meta теги типа viewport. Надо либо изменить значение width либо вообще убрать этот тег

Comment: @Skywave Подскажите пожалуйста в каких файлах они обычно обитают

Comment: В заголовке страницы в секции <head>

Comment: Насчет файлов не знаю. Зависит от того как страница строится

Comment: @Skywave спасибо, помогло, можете написать ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

За область просмотра отвечает `meta` тег `viewport`

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Необходимо либо убрать его из секции `<head>` либо изменить на нужное значение.

Comment: `Необходимо либо убрать его` Может всё таки добавить, а не убрать? Если убрать всё будет плохо

Comment: @MasterAlex Про масштабирование подобное я сам узнал недавно, этот тег стал использовать тоже недавно, поэтому абсолютно точно не скажу. Но до того как я его стал использовать на сайтах, они у меня масштабировались так, чтобы весь сайт влез в экран - как и требовалось автору.

Comment: Насколько я знаю механику работы этой строки, работает она как раз наоборот, без неё сайт может вылезать за границы устройства, а в этой строке задаётся  `width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0`, и это значит что ширина контента будет равна ширине устройства, и масштаб отображения 1 к 1. Иначе бы эта строка не получила бы такой популярности на сайтах, именно она позволяет без оптимизации под мобилу получать удобоваримый вид сайта. Исходя из написанного мной, ваше предложение убрать эту строку будет вводить пользователей в заблуждение.